# How to embed youtube player in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I had gone through with the previous question and wrote simple code..

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <video src=\"point/to/mov\"></video>\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    //[videoView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WL2l_Q1AR_Q"]]];
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
    [videoView release];
}
```

if use the "html" is it not showing...
but we load the url directly as i commented it is working fine...

Can anyone help me out of this issue..